# Carregar uma imagem local dentro de uma Webview

Tags: html, react, react-native, webview

Tenho um componente `WebView` que carrega uma `String` `HTML`, o problema é que não consigo carregar uma imagem local dentro dessa `WebView`. A imagem esta dentro da pasta `'../img/imagem.png'` e quando coloco esse "endereço" como source da `<img>` ela não carrega, alguma luz!?

```
const paragraphs = ` <img src="../img/imagem.png"/> `;

export default class Demo extends PureComponent {
    render () {
        return (
            <WebView 
         source={{html:paragraphs}} 
         scalesPageToFit/>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que você não usa o componente  em vez de  apenas renderizar uma imagem. link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image